# Ordenar una lista de productos por orden alfabetico inverso en Python

Tags: python

Me piden ordenar una lista de tuplas que tengo en un archivo, uso

```
lista = sorted(lista, reverse = True)
print(lista)
```

Y cuando corro el programa me aparecen los pasos previos que hizo hasta llegar a la lista ordenada, lo que quisiera saber es como hacer para que me aparezca solamente la lista ordenada sin ver los pasos previos.
Muchas gracias!

Comment: (?) ¿A qué te refieres con eso de que te aparecen los pasos previos? El código que muestras debe imprimir sólo la lista ordenada ¿No será que en el código previo que no muestras tienes más `print()`?

Comment: A mi el código a continuación me funciona sin ningún problema: 

    `lista = ['a','b','c','d']
    lista = sorted(lista, reverse = True)
    print(lista)`
Verifica que no tengas impresiones aparte.

Comment: Es el unico print que tengo en la programacion, por eso me parece raro que me aparezca asi.

Comment: Ya encontre mi error, tenia una mala tabulacion, mil gracias!